# Microsoft Partner O365 Developer Account benefit expired - unable to delete or renew

Tags: office365

Our team signed up as an ISV partner and an O365 Developer Account was included. We created and it's supposed to expire every 90 days. We didn't use it do to other issues and are now ready to use it but it expired and delete isn't working, nothing happens. How can I get support to delete and start over or delete and wait in developer jail until another obligatory 60 days has passed (according to the website). Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried to delete my profile and restart. I have waited until the system delete date of Jan 31, 2024 for auto-delete passed and nothing happened. I have deleted, waited a couple of days, and attempted to create a profile again with the same results.